# Encrypting a SQL Login in a Python program using MD5

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, config, md5

I have a python program that accesses SQL databases with the database login currently encoded in base64 in a text file. I'd like to encode the login instead using MD5 and store it in a config file, but after some research, I couldn't find much on the topic. Could someone point me in the right direction on where to start?

Comment: Encrypting, encoding and hashing are very different things.

Comment: The database story has not really anything to do with the question, does it? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5, unfortunately, is a *hash signature* protocol, not an encryption protocol.  It is used to generate strings that are used to detect even the very-slightest change to the value from which the MD5 hash was produced.  But . . . (by design) . . . you *cannot* recover the value that was originally used to produce the signature!

If you are working in a corporate, "intra-net" setting, consider using LDAP *(Microsoft OpenDirectory)* or some other form of authorization/authentication, *in lieu of* "passwords."  In this scenario, the security department authorizes your application to do certain things, and they provide you with an otherwise-meaningless token with which to do it.  The database uses the presented token, along with other rules controlled only by the security department, to *recognize* your script and to grant selected access to it.  The token is "useless if stolen."

If you do still need to use passwords, you'll need to find a different way to securely store them.  MD5 cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/hashlib.html

```
import hashlib
print( hashlib.md5(b"stackoverflow").hexdigest() )
```